# Tips for understanding big project fast?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project

I've got a job and many new things to be learned. The first thing is to understand big project, writtened mostly in C++, using Visual Studio. So, I see a statement, and I want to find its definition. Using Ctr+F to search through entire solution, and if multiple libraries have different function but same name, I would have many result that I don't know which one is the definition of the statement. And vice versal, I see a definition, but I don't know which statements are its invoker.

Is there any tips for my issue? Any suggestion is very appreciated. Thanks (And please, I don't want to go to debug mode, since It takes lot of time to build, and I'm lazy rofl).

Comment: Visual Studio has a "show definition" functionality. Try right-clicking on the name and look at the pop-up menu. I've witnessed problems with it, but it usually is better than using ctrl-F.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with a tool like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl).

I find it useful when I start to work on a new codebase.

Just tweak some parameter in the configuration file and run doxygen against your code. For your needs you could change:

- `CALL_GRAPH = YES`. A graphical [call graph](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) is drawn for each function showing the functions that the function directly or indirectly calls
- `CALLER_GRAPH = YES`. A graphical caller graph is drawn for each function showing the functions that the function is directly or indirectly called by

Probably also:

- `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`, `HAVE_DOT = YES`, `UML_LOOK = YES` to generate a class diagram (see [Graphviz + doxygen to generate UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484879/graphviz-doxygen-to-generate-uml-class-diagrams)).

The nice things is that even if the documentation isn't already available, you can extract a lot of useful information (and while learning you could start documenting the code).

Anyway it takes time.